# python dask to_csv delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dask, delimiter, dask-dataframe

I have a question to setup delimiter with `python dask`.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df_out.to_csv("path/out.csv", single_file = True)
```

How can I set a `delimiter`? It seems that there is no parameter for delimiter.

I got the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/folderpathg/out.csv/005.part'
```

Comment: "CSV" stands for "comma separated values".  If you're not using commas, then it's not a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `sep` option:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(range(10), range(10)), columns=list('ab'))

import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

ddf.to_csv('test.txt', sep='|', single_file=True, index=False)
```

Comment: I got the error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/folderpath/out.csv/005.part'` and what does `npartitions` mean here... and the folder exists there...

Comment: Looks like you are trying to write to a folder that doesn't exist.

Comment: `npartitions` is just a way to split the pandas dataframe into multiple dask dataframe partitions, it's not important in the code, just a way to show that the code will work for dask dataframes with multiple partitions.

Comment: I would recommend trying to run the snippet in my answer, if it works, while your code does not, then the problem is not with your dask/pandas libraries. So, one thing I would try is deleting `/folderpath/out.csv/005.part`, including `/folderpath/out.csv` folder and then trying to re-run the `.to_csv` code again.

Comment: Do I need to add `*` sign in filename? `df_out.to_csv("path/out*.csv", single_file = True)`. I'm so confused on `https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_csv`

Comment: If you use `single_file=True` option, then dask will save a single file and no `*` is needed. If you don't specify that option, then dask will save each partition into a separate csv file, so `*` tells dask where to put partition number (`001`, `002`, etc).